# Add resource policy for API in CloudFormation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

We have a NodeJS lambda project in CodeStar. We have gotten it to work, and we have secured the API with an API key.

Is it possible to add a Resource Policy for the API in the CloudFormation template? So we don't have to add a Resource Policy in the web console every time we create a new project/API.

We have tried but haven't gotten it to work, and we can't find any documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by API. The lambda project is an API? Are you using API Gateway? Do you want to protect a secret key? For me, it is not clear what you want to add to Resource Policy.

Comment: Sorry @tyron, I was a bit unclear. The CodeStar project indeed uses API Gateway. We have secured the API somewhat by adding an API key, but we want to secure it even more by IP whitelisting the Dev stage (office IP) and whitelisting our VPC for the Stage and Prod stages so other servers can call the API.The API is hooked up to a lambda function.

Comment: We haven't gotten the Resource Policy to work, I put it in a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933477/how-can-i-make-an-ip-vpc-whitelist-for-an-api-in-api-gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doc is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-restapi.html

and it should look something like this

`Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  Properties:
    ApiKeySourceType: String
    BinaryMediaTypes:
      - String
    Body: JSON object
    BodyS3Location:
      S3Location
    CloneFrom: String
    Description: String
    EndpointConfiguration: EndpointConfiguration
    FailOnWarnings: Boolean
    MinimumCompressionSize: Integer
    Name: String
    Parameters:
      String: String
    Policy: JSON object`

Comment: it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

A complete example for a private API Gateway with resource policy included (in this case only access from a previously defined VPC endpoint is allowed) can be found below.

```
InterfaceEndpoint:
  Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint'
  Properties:
    VpcEndpointType: Interface
    ServiceName: !Sub 'com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.execute-api'
    PrivateDnsEnabled: true
    VpcId: !Ref VPC
    SubnetIds: 
      - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
      - !Ref PrivateSubnet2
    SecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref InterfaceSecurityGroup

privateApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  Properties:
    Description: Private API Gateway
    EndpointConfiguration:
      Types:
        - PRIVATE
      VpcEndpointIds:
        - !Ref InterfaceEndpoint
    Name: privateApi
    Policy:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: "*"
          Action: execute-api:Invoke
          Resource:
            - execute-api:/*
        - Effect: Deny
          Principal: "*"
          Action: execute-api:Invoke
          Resource:
            - execute-api:/*
          Condition:
            StringNotEquals:
              aws:SourceVpce: !Ref InterfaceEndpoint
```